# Which verb tense should I use in the example below?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

I’m wondering which tense (present or past) to use to describe a  hypothetical outcome of an event that might happen.

*Example*: We have completed Test A, the result is not known yet. Depending on the outcome of Test A, we might or might not need to do a Test B.

Given that we are uncertain if Test B will be needed, but I wanted to talk about the possible outcome of an uncertain events. So if I wanted to say “if Test B **turns/turned** out bad, we **will/would** need to do a Test C.

Which tense should I use? I’m thinking Past Tense..

Answer (score 1):

You are considering the future, that has not happened yet so you need to use

> if Test B **turns** out bad, we **will** need to do a Test C.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, if you are not sure whether you need to do test B even - this is quite formal:

> If I were to do test B and it were to turn out bad, I would need/have to do test C.

I don't love the "turn out bad" here, so I might say:

> If I were to do test B and it didn't go well, I would need/have to do test C.

A step down in formality, would be:

> If I had/needed to do test B and it [[were to go]/[went] badly]/[didn't go well], I would have/need to do test C.

Finally, a slightly shorter version of these:

> If test B were to [turn out bad]/[not go well] (should I have to do it - implied), I would need/have to do test C.

Can't change the "were to" to a simple past tense here since we don't know it will necessarily occur.

I also prefer "have to" instead of "need to" in all of these, but not essential.  "Need to" maybe sounds too formal.

Hope this helps.